# Running dymanic SQL stored procedure results in catching syntax alert on other line

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to use dynamic SQL to populate a statement and run it:

```
DECLARE @ENTY_ID INT;
DECLARE @FIELD_ID INT;
DECLARE @VALUE NVARCHAR(50);
DECLARE @ENTY_TABLE_NAME NVARCHAR(500);
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @ENTY_ID = 1;
SET @FIELD_ID = 90;
SET @VALUE = '0';

SET @ENTY_TABLE_NAME = 
(SELECT TOP 1 ENTY_TABLE_NAME
FROM ENTY
WHERE ENTY.ENTY_ID=@ENTY_ID);

SET @SQL = '
SELECT DISTINCT ATTR_VAL 
FROM @ENTY_TABLE_NAME
WHERE FIELD_ID = @FIELD_ID AND ATTR_VAL LIKE %@VALUE%
ORDER BY ATTR_VAL';

SET @SQL = replace(@SQL, '@ENTY_TABLE_NAME', @ENTY_TABLE_NAME + '_ATTR');
SET @SQL = replace(@SQL, '@FIELD_ID', @FIELD_ID);
SET @SQL = replace(@SQL, '@VALUE', @VALUE);

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL;
```

When I run all of the lines EXCEPT the last EXEC, the command completes successfully.

When I run it all together I get:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near '0'.
```

I don't see how a syntax issue is being called. How can I get this to run the query in the @SQL variable?

Comment: Can you please `SELECT` the `@SQL` variable to see what it constructed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the single quotes in `LIKE %@VALUE%`, it should be `LIKE ' %@VALUE%'`:

```
SET @SQL = '
SELECT DISTINCT ATTR_VAL 
FROM @ENTY_TABLE_NAME
WHERE FIELD_ID = @FIELD_ID AND ATTR_VAL LIKE ''%@VALUE%''
ORDER BY ATTR_VAL';
```